# Link will not open after class is added

Tags: jquery

I have four links in my menu. I have created function that will add class "link-selected" after I click on any link. My problem is it will not open the link when its clicked. How can I fix that?

```
$('.container .link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.container .link').removeClass('link-selected');
    $(this).addClass('link-selected');
});
```

Comment: What do you think `e.preventDefault()` does?

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault();` and read its definition here: https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: You will navigate away from the page after you click the link anyway so you wont see the changes js has made. Not unless you open the link in a new tab.

Comment: i think you need to learn jQuery first, before fighting with this situation ....

Answer (score 0):

With e.preventDefault() you prevent the default Action for clicking on this link. So to have a functionality for a link, remove this line.

But then the rest of your JS code is not needed because you get redirected on a new page anyways. So what do you want to achieve? I think there may be a better way on how to solve your underlying problem/achieve the desired effect.

Comment: what Im trying to do is add class "link-selected" to a link that was clicked and its page loaded. I want to give different color to a link.

Comment: your problem can't be solved with jQuery (or Javascript in general). The additional class must be in the html from the start.